# Como usar informações de banco de dados de outra aplicação?

Tags: banco-de-dados

Gostaria de saber quais os procedimentos para poder desenvolver um sistema utilizando informações de um banco de dados de um sistema de terceiros.

Explicando: no meu trabalho nós usamos um sistema desktop (SIABI) para gerenciamento de processos como cadastro de livros, empréstimos, devoluções, etc. Eu gostaria de construir uma aplicação com algumas funcionalidades que não existem no SIABI, mas para isso eu precisaria poder acessar o banco de dados utilizado pelo SIABI. Como isso é feito? Eu entraria em contato com o dono do SIABI e pediria a ele que fizesse o favor de me dar acesso ao banco de dados? E só por curiosidade, essa é uma necessidade frequente para os programadores?

Por exemplo, no SIABI não existe a opção de exibir uma lista de livros que não tem imagem de capa cadastrada, então queria desenvolver uma aplicação à parte, que complementasse o SIABI, com funcionalidades que o SIABI não possui. A ideia seria continuar usando o SIABI normalmente e usar a minha aplicação somente quando o SIABI não fosse o suficiente.

Sou totalmente iniciante em programação, por isso, se der, não usem muitos termos técnicos.

Comment: O negocio parece meio fechado, como é web pode ser que exista a possibildiade deles terem webservices disponibilizados para clientes, mas so entrando em contato
http://www.siabi.com.br/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

@Reily, vai muito da negociação que o seu cliente/chefe teve com o proprietário deste sistema. Porque se não houver nenhuma conversa antes, o dono do SIABI não terá interesse nenhum em ajudar a desenvolver um sistema web que provavelmente vá futuramente inutilizar o dele.

Caso isso não seja empecilho, como o @Krismorte comentou, você pode consultá-los a respeito da disponibilização de webservices.

Se não, você poderia descrever quais informações precisa (nome do aluno, matricula, código do livro, etc.) para eles prepararem *views* e disponibilizar um usuário na base de dados sem tantos privilégios (somente para consultar essas views).

Ou então se ele for bem parceiro de vocês, preparar um dump da base para voce trabalhar local.

Comment: Então, pelo que entendi, eu dependo realmente da aceitação do proprietário do software, mesmo as informações sendo sobre minha empresa. Dump não serviria a menos que fosse constantemente atualizado, e ainda assim, eu não poderia inserir dados no banco real, o que impossibilitaria muitas funcionalidades que eu pretendia implementar. Não conhecia o termo webservices, estou pesquisando já. Obrigada!